# Recursively add specific number of days to a fixed date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am creating a spreadsheet that allows me to see the next due date of automated payments.

For one service I pay for, the first payment was taken on 10/09/22 (dd-mm-yy). Each subsequent payment is taken 30 days later (this could differ for each service), so 10/10/22, 09/11/22 and so on.

My current spreadsheet:

[image]

The formula used in C4 is: `= A4+(B4 * DATEDIF(A4, B$1, "m"))`. I'm using datedif to calculate the number of months difference between the start month and current month.

The problem is that it is showing the next payment date as 09/11/2022 - as this date has already passed, I would like the next payment date to be shown (09/12/2022).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! Let's try to do it together.
What date was yesterday? `=TODAY()-1`

How many days have passed since the first payment until yesterday? `=TODAY()-1-A4`

How many full pay periods fit in this time period? `=INT((TODAY()-1-A4)/B4)`

In how many days should the next payment be due? `=B4*(INT((TODAY()-1-A4)/B4)+1)`

What date will it be? `=A4+B4*(INT((TODAY()-1-A4)/B4)+1)`

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed. P.S I think you meant how many days have passed since the first payment in the second paragraph (rather than last payment)

Comment: @TheCodesee Yes, that's right, you got it right.